# Подключение блока при прокрутке к месту или через некоторое время после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, php

На сайте https://alisa-music.ru/ есть блок [Клипы](https://alisa-music.ru/#Clip) с множеством Youtube `ifarme` 
что приводит к долгой загрузке сайта, и соответственно снижению рейтинга в поисковиках. При том что пользователи редко "в первую очередь" интересуются этим блоком.

Сейчас использую подключение блока через JS через 1500 ms после загрузки страницы, что убрало задержку для пользователя, но несильно повеяло на рейтинг Google Pagespeed

Как я могу подключать этот блок при прокрутке к нему или через несколько секунд (1-2) после открытия страницы?

Comment: Используй технологию Intersection Observer. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Используйте scrollTop(). К примеру, если scrollTop будет больше определенного значения, то отображать блок с клипами.
Или по документации https://learn.javascript.ru/onscroll

Comment: P.S id="ClipItem" - должен быть уникальным.

Comment: А лучше использовать API Google и загружать все видео которые есть в плэйсисте. Т.е. добавлять в код  ничего не нужно будет. Достаточно сформировать цикл который будет это рендерить при достижении определенном значении top.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=ru